# Перехват SSL траффика

Tags: ssl, firefox, c++

Требуется перехватить траффик flash приложения запущенном в firefox. Как это сделать?

Вижу варианты:

1. Через прокси. Но по большому счету тут уже зашифрованный траффик и ничего с ним не сделаешь.
2. Через сам firefox, через расширения или перехват функции перед шифрованием.

Comment: wireshark? или Вам нужно обязательно программно?

Comment: Как wireshark поможет расшифровать трафик?

Comment: http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL

Comment: Может я неправильно написал? Мне нужно получить данные передающиеся через https в изначальном не зашифрованном виде.

Comment: Вам нужен файл с rsa-ключем. А вот его нужно будет найти. А траффик уже wireshark расшифрует.

Comment: Хорошая шутка про закрытый ключ.

Comment: Траффик шифруется до отправки в канал, а значит возможны только следующие пути:  

1. Дебаг программы.  
2. Способ, предложенный @KoVadim.  
3. При наличии корневого сертификата можно воспользоваться.Man-In-Middle способом. (Перехват подключения, выдача своего сертификата клиенту, установление соединения с внешним сервером с последующим проксированием траффика клиента.

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить в Firefox свой сертификат и использовать sslsplit. Если флеш использует свою базу сертификатов, то тогда нужно и туда.

Также обычный FireBug (или встроенный в Firefox аналог) часто показывает запросы от флеша.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/download/), он выступает в роли локального прокси. При его установке Charles автоматически предложит установить плагин для firefox.

Далее нужно установить корневой сертификат: меню Tools(Инструменты?) > Charles >  "Install Charles Root Certificate".

Так же в самой программе нужно будет добавить адрес сайта, трафик которого вы хотите перехватывать: Proxy Settings, вкладка SSL.

Сам давно не пользовался, так что больше подсказать не могу, читайте документацию на официальном сайте.